# Embedding a Torus into Plane with Cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I have a complex plane with two horizontal cuts $[-\alpha \pm i/2, \alpha \pm i/2]$ for real $\alpha$.  We can imagine gluing the two cuts to get a torus with complex parameter $\tau$.  Thinking of the fundamental parallelogram of the torus, we can have the "upper-most" A-cycle of the torus map into the cut on the complex plane.

According the the literature, the function $$-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\theta'_{3}(\pi x | \tau)}{\theta_{3}(\pi x | \tau)}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x \in \big[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\big]$$

maps the upper-most A-cycle of the torus to the subset $[-\alpha , \alpha]$ of the real axis.  (The theta functions are of course the Jacobi Theta Functions.)  However, when I try to verify this using Mathematica, I find that only when $\rm{Re}(\tau)=0$ does that function map nicely into the real numbers; otherwise, it has imaginary parts too.

Any idea why this is happening?  I need that function to map into the real numbers for all $\tau \in \mathbb{H} \, / \, \rm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}) $.

Comment: Do you remember the literature source from which you took the map?